# Outlook search DASL syntax and diatrics/accented letters

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am using the [AdvancedSearch feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933(v=office.15).aspx) in a VSTO Outlook addin.

I would like the search to ignore accent. For example, in a contact search, I would like the search to find "Grégoire" when entering "Gre". It does not work when I use a DASL query of the form:

> "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8005001f"
>   LIKE '%greg%'

This query has been forged using the View Filter on a folder: *View > Filter > SQL tab*

In addition, I noticed that the Outlook basic search ignores accent (see image below).

[image]

Does anyone know a solution to make the DASL query "accent insensitive"?